# Looking for antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, radicals, substitution

Find
$$\int\log\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)dx$$
I used the subtitution
$$\sqrt{x}=\tan{y}$$
but i the integral became too long
and involves $$\int\sec^3{y}dy$$
and also $$\int\sec^5{y}dy$$ but it solvable so i search for a simple solution if exist ?
Note
$$\log$$ is the natural logarithm

Comment: But $\sqrt x-\sqrt{x+1}<0$

Comment: Not sure it is the better way but you could try to integrate by parts saying that your function equals to itself times $1$ and antiderivating $1$ ( supposing it is the opposite in log's argument )

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not make sense as kingW3 has pointed out in the comment. Please edit your question.

Comment: I don’t understand why some mathematicians insist on using $\log$ for the natural logarithm when $\ln$ literally stands for *logarithmus naturalis*. As long as we’re dedicating a paragraph of the question‘s body to clarify this, could someone explain to me why this convention exists? It’s quicker and clearer to write/type $\ln$ anyways.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I believe $\log$ was historically the natural log until programmers started using it for base 10, and $\ln$ was born.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\ln(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})dx=x\ln(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})-\int \frac{x\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}dx=$$
$$=x\ln(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}dx=...$$ and substitute $\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}=t.$